# Can converting MyISAM to InnoDB cause problems?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I am changing an old MySQL database table which is still in MyISAM. I'd like to change it to InnoDB, but I don't know whether it can cause problems and it's a pretty important table so I don't want to break anything.

So my question: can it cause problems when I convert a MyISAM table to InnoDB?

Comment: Maybe perform some testing on your test server? You **do** have one? MyISAM is being deprecated in any case.

Comment: Hi joshua, the answer you looking for is here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html

Comment: @Vérace where did you find hat MyISAM is being deprecated? I have never heard of this before.

Comment: I got it from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19638284/470530). Bill Karwin was a Percona (?) consultant and is widely regarded as an SQL guru.

Comment: Version 8.0 removes MyISAM; they announced it at the Oracle conference last fall.  (I think I saw Bill there.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it can cause a number of troubles.  However, troubles are rare.

There is a list of possible 'troubles' that you might encounter, including possible solutions in a discussion format [in the MariaDB knowledge base.](https://web.archive.org/web/20220504012549/https://mariadb.com/kb/en/converting-tables-from-myisam-to-innodb/).

There is another list in a more concise format with bullet points and discussion to be found on Rick James's [MySQL documentation site](https://web.archive.org/web/20211125165403/http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb).

Aside from the various possible trade offs and data issues, one important bit of advice is: do not change the tables in the databases `mysql`, `information_schema`, or `performance_schema`. That can cause serious trouble.

Comment: Thanks, good answer. Don't think it'll give me much problems. And no, I wasn't planning on changing anything to mysql, information_schema or performance_schema. Cheers!

Comment: @Rick James Just had to say that I found it funny that I didn't notice until _after_ posting an edit crediting your link that you were the author of this answer. I found your page a bit easier to follow than that MariaDB one, so thanks for that! Anyway. :)